# How to correctly rebuild my application after renaming package?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've renamed my package name using Project -> Android Tools -> Rename Package. I've also cleaned my project and changed the config.xml widget ID to reflect the same name. When I try and run the simulator and/or my project in general, I get multiple `Failed to load properties file for project`. Is there anything I am missing changing my package name to correctly run my application? Thanks!

edit: I am receiving this error: The declared package "ca.treatfinder" does not match the expected package "com.treatfinder"

Comment: Eclipse is dumb and many times a simple clean and rebuild fixes issues.

Comment: Check your manifest, check your buildpath, check you packages, and do a project cleaning. Eclipse -> Project -> Clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build it...In eclipse go to project->build and clean...when you want to rename sth you can use rightclick->refactor->rename...then theses issues won't come around

Comment: It lets me run the simulator now but I get a "Unfortunately projectname has stopped." Any ideas?